# MigLayout - using multiple constraints

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I want to my panel a table which `growx` and `wraps` the next component. I did that:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(""));       
panel.add(showTable(), "growx wrap");
```

However, I am getting the error: `Illegal Constraint: 'growx wrap'`

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > panel.add(showTable(), "growx, wrap");

Note the comma.